# Forms paste javascript into db

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, symfony

My action is writing the content of the form  including JavaScript code into the DB. How can I get rid of the JavaScript if a user is pasting JavaScript into my from or don't make it executeable. Because If I am going to get it from the db and do an echo, the JavaScript is executing. This is of course (depending of the action) a main security problem.

E.g.: Paste into my form "name" or "textarea":  `<s c r i p t> aler..</ s c r i p t >`

My form looks like this:

```
->add('name', 'text', array(
   'constraints' => array(new Length(array('max' => 255, 'maxMessage' => $this->get('translator')->trans('maxlength255.name', array(), 'forms')))),
   'required' => false,
   'attr' => array('oninvalid' => "setCustomValidity('" . $this->get('translator')->trans('oninvalid.name', array(), 'forms') . "')",
      'onchange' => "try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}",
      'placeholder' => $this->get('translator')->trans('placeholder.name', array(), 'forms'),)
))
->add('message', 'textarea', array(
   'constraints' => array(new Length(array('min' => 5,  'max' => 5000, 'maxMessage' => $this->get('translator')->trans('maxlength5000.message', array(), 'forms'), 'minMessage' => $this->get('translator')->trans('minlength5.message', array(), 'forms')))),
   'required' => false,
   'attr' => array('oninvalid' => "setCustomValidity('" . $this->get('translator')->trans('oninvalid.message', array(), 'forms') . "')",
      'onchange' => "try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}",
      'placeholder' => $this->get('translator')->trans('placeholder.message', array(), 'forms'),)
))
```

I am sorry if the question is already asked, but I couldn't find it on stackoverflow. Then please refer a link to that! THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT's a bad practice instead of putting js code in database put the variable information as

serialized data later build them using loops...

however if you want to put this first convert this to htmlentities using

**htmlentities();** function

on retrieval use **html_entity_decode();** function

to decode and get the orginal source code...

Comment: Okay, thanks. But you don't might know if there is an automatic way to do it in symfony2? So I don't need to the function htmlentities()?